# What are the implications of not having explicit static private IP for Windows Server 2012?

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012, static-ip

In more details:

We have 2 Windows Servers 2012 running SQL Server Web **on Amazon EC2 in the same VPC**.

Network adapters are configured with static private IP-s via AWS console.

At Widows level, however when you go to Network Adapter Properties/IPV4/Properties it shows:

**Obtain an IP address automatically**

**Obtain DNS server automatically**

So what happens is that each time network adapters receive the same IP dynamically (for instance, 10.0.0.20 for one server and 10.0.0.21 for another).

Are there any implications of having Windows Server (or SQL Server) configured that way?

Should I in addition to assignment via Amazon AWS also set the same static IP for network adapter at Windows level?

Or should I set it to dynamic as AWS level and assign static addresses at Windows level?

Answer (score 1):

You *always* want to use DHCP in EC2. If you use the `--private-ip` option when creating your instances, your instances will always get the IP address.

Comment: To clarify: you recommend leave everything at Windows OS level as-is ("Obtain an IP address automatically" and "Obtain DNS server automatically"), correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.